# Flink Task Manager did not read db. Properties

Tags: apache-flink

I distributed the flink application to the flink and found a strange phenomenon.

The phenomenon is that JobManager finds and reads db.properties without problems, but TaskManager cannot find db.properties due to errors as follows. May I ask for your advice on this part?

```
2022-04-05 16:32:54,730 ERROR       

### Error building SqlSession.

### The error may exist in SQL Mapper Configuration

### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: java.io.IOException: Could not find resource properties/db.properties

org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 

### Error building SqlSession.

### The error may exist in SQL Mapper Configuration

### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: java.io.IOException: Could not find resource properties/db.properties

    at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:23) ~[mybatis-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]

    at org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.build(SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.java:51) ~[mybatis-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]

    at org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.build(SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.java:35) ~[mybatis-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]

    at com.watchtek.watchall.common.manager.MapperManager.getSqlSessionFactory(MapperManager.java:76) ~[Watchall_Cep_TMS_Common-12.0.1.jar:?]

    at com.watchtek.watchall.common.manager.MapperManager.getSqlSession(MapperManager.java:91) ~[Watchall_Cep_TMS_Common-12.0.1.jar:?]

    at com.watchtek.watchall.common.manager.MapperManager.getMapper(MapperManager.java:44) ~[Watchall_Cep_TMS_Common-12.0.1.jar:?]

    at com.watchtek.watchall.modules.tms.info.FlinkEventInfo.setGroupMap(FlinkEventInfo.java:86) ~[blob_p-34d591a09fd41c9e56398af8a7fc1f8baeb41b70-ea63057a682d68a1a50fae7424178f95:?]

    at com.watchtek.watchall.modules.tms.info.FlinkEventInfo.initialize(FlinkEventInfo.java:61) ~[blob_p-34d591a09fd41c9e56398af8a7fc1f8baeb41b70-ea63057a682d68a1a50fae7424178f95:?]

    at com.watchtek.watchall.modules.tms.info.FlinkEventInfo.<init>(FlinkEventInfo.java:53) ~[blob_p-34d591a09fd41c9e56398af8a7fc1f8baeb41b70-ea63057a682d68a1a50fae7424178f95:?]

    at com.watchtek.watchall.modules.tms.info.FlinkEventInfo.<init>(FlinkEventInfo.java:27) ~[blob_p-34d591a09fd41c9e56398af8a7fc1f8baeb41b70-ea63057a682d68a1a50fae7424178f95:?]

    at com.watchtek.watchall.modules.tms.info.FlinkEventInfo$Singleton.<clinit>(FlinkEventInfo.java:43) ~[blob_p-34d591a09fd41c9e56398af8a7fc1f8baeb41b70-ea63057a682d68a1a50fae7424178f95:?]

    at com.watchtek.watchall.modules.tms.info.FlinkEventInfo.getInstance(FlinkEventInfo.java:48) ~[blob_p-34d591a09fd41c9e56398af8a7fc1f8baeb41b70-ea63057a682d68a1a50fae7424178f95:?]

    at com.watchtek.watchall.modules.tms.service.TmsEventService.checkCondition(TmsEventService.java:240) ~[blob_p-34d591a09fd41c9e56398af8a7fc1f8baeb41b70-ea63057a682d68a1a50fae7424178f95:?]

    at com.watchtek.watchall.modules.tms.service.TmsEventService$CepFilter.filter(TmsEventService.java:181) ~[blob_p-34d591a09fd41c9e56398af8a7fc1f8baeb41b70-ea63057a682d68a1a50fae7424178f95:?]

    at com.watchtek.watchall.modules.tms.service.TmsEventService$CepFilter.filter(TmsEventService.java:117) ~[blob_p-34d591a09fd41c9e56398af8a7fc1f8baeb41b70-ea63057a682d68a1a50fae7424178f95:?
```

I analyzed the difference between TaskManager and JobManager, but what is the difference between the same process?

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause is because either the file either only exists on the JobManager and not on the TaskManagers, or because the TaskManagers can't access the file.